# make default value in textbox not change till text is entered using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please check my fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/7995m/ . In the fiddle, the default text disappears as soon as the text box is clicked. I want the default text to not change till text is written. The following is my code:-

```
$(".defaultText").focus(function(srcc)
{
    if ($(this).val() == $(this)[0].title)
    {
        $(this).removeClass("defaultTextActive");
        $(this).val("");
    }
});

$(".defaultText").blur(function()
{
    if ($(this).val() == "")
    {
        $(this).addClass("defaultTextActive");
        $(this).val($(this)[0].title);
    }
});

$(".defaultText").blur();
```

Comment: I suggest you use the placeholder attribute instead of using default values for inputs

Comment: there are two option,add a polyfill and learn how to use them..or just  follow my answer...both of them do the same thing.

Comment: There are pros and cons of each solution. Modernizr is a useful tool to learn and doesn't take very much time to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you started with using the HTML5 placeholder attribute http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

It is commonly used in web applications.

If the browser you're targeting doesn't support placeholders, you can create a polyfill using modernizr to support the html5 attribute. Here is a polyfill using jquery https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

You can find additional polyfills for placeholders or other html5 attributes here:
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Here is a link to modernizr http://modernizr.com/

After creating the polyfill, the modernizr will detect if the browser rendering the page supports the placeholder attribute and if it doesn't, the polyfill will emulate the behavior. This way, the HTML code isn't polluted with a custom solution and future browsers will be unaffected if they support placeholders.

This is really the best way to go. Creating a custom solution is great in the short-term, but using a polyfill like this helps to avoid potential problems in the long term, such as new browsers not being compatible with the custom solution a year down the road. Using a polyfill to fill in the functionality for the HTML5 attribute will ensure your application won't break in the future while allowing for the same functionality in older browsers. It also aids in the readability of your html code.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce your no.of lines of code,By using  `placeholder` attribute.

Ex

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Your first name...">
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7995m/2/)

Comment: need to check html 5 compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7995m/1/)

just replace your `focus` by `keydown`.Placeholder is a good solution,but IE7,8,9 does not support it.So instead of using some js(there are som polyfills available),I would suggest you to continue with this code itself.

```
$(".defaultText").keydown(function(srcc)
{
    if ($(this).val() == $(this)[0].title)
    {
        $(this).removeClass("defaultTextActive");
        $(this).val("");
    }
});

$(".defaultText").blur(function()
{
    if ($(this).val() == "")
    {
        $(this).addClass("defaultTextActive");
        $(this).val($(this)[0].title);
    }
});

$(".defaultText").blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `placeholder` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to achieve this, although it is not quite the standard behaviour use this instead your focus event:

```
$(".defaultText").keydown(function(srcc)
{

        $(this).removeClass("defaultTextActive");
        $(this).val("");

});
```

but definitely use the placeholder tag, which is the right way to go